# Open source public transit directions

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am planning on hosting a map server to serve out directions to my webapp. I need to be able to give public transit directions, time estimate using said public transit, and also offer search for businesses/poi much like google places api.

Can this be done with OpenStreetMap + something else?

Comment: Are you seeking [softwarerecs.se] or something else?

Comment: Have you googled: gtfs software ?

Answer (score 4):

OpenStreetMap doesn't contain timetable information, which is essential to any public transport routing.

Instead, you'll need to find timetable data for the services you're interested in. This is often provided in a format called GTFS. [Transitland](https://transit.land/) is a good place to start looking.

Then you'll need routing software which can consume GTFS feeds. [OpenTripPlanner](http://www.opentripplanner.org/) is the best-known.